# .htaccess if statement?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I haven't worked with .htaccess too much. Looking to do something like this:

When user types in domain.com/path it is then pulled from domain.com/index.php/path/to/file

UNLESS

someones goes to domain.com/admin

How can an add a exception or if statement for a few words that i dont want to redirect?

Comment: Generally a `RewriteCond` can be used as `if` for url rewriting rules. See severfault: [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules](http://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-ask)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a rule for the admin rewrite first and use `[L]` at the end to tell .htaccess this is the last rule it should follow. Then, put your other rules after it.

Example:

```
RewriteRule ^admin(/?)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/to/file.php?id=$1
```

Using the `-` after the match rule means it won't rewrite it, it'll just go to the path that was provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a RewriteCond rule to exclude stuff from the rewrite rule.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```